# mkdir() not Working on Android 11 & Android 12

Tags: android, api, android-studio, android-11, android-12

I am trying to create directory in Android/data folder with below code:

```
String rootDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "";
File f = new File(rootDirectory + "/Android/data/com.moh.phc.phcis");
f.mkdir();
```

but id didn't create the directory in Android 11 & Android 12, although it created the directory and worked on Android 10 and below versions, also I gave the permission to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Is there anyway to create the directory in Android 11 & Android 12?

Thanks.

Comment: if (!f.exists()) if (!f.mkdir()) return;. Display a Toast too to inform the user if mkdir fails.

Comment: Better use getExternalFilesDir() instead of hard coding that path.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it, it seems that Android 11 & Android 12 cannot create directories in Android/data folder, so I changed the path to:

```
File f = new File(rootDirectory + "/Android/com.moh.phc.phcis");
```

Problem Solved.